# How to change a text value by requesting a PHP file thanks to AJAX? (Without refreshing the page)

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm learning AJAX and want to create a really simple web app to use my knowledge in the "real world".

I'm trying to calculte different percentages of a user input value, and make it appears on the webpage, without refreshing, thanks to AJAX.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="warmupForm" class="form">
      <label for="userWorkLoad">Work load (in kgs)</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="userWorkLoad" id="userWorkLoad">
      <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form> 

<div id="#output">This is where I want the result to be shown with AJAX</div>
```

Here is some of my PHP code, for you to get the idea:

```
# Get the user input (work load in kgs)
if (isset($_POST['userWorkLoad'])) {
    $workload = $_POST['userWorkLoad'];

    # Avoid JS hacking
    $workload = htmlspecialchars($workload);
}

# CALCULATION #
# Calculate 55% of the work load (1st warm up set)
$FirstWarmupSet = ($workload * 0.55);

# Calculate 70% of the work load (2nd warm up set)
$SecondWarmupSet = ($workload * 0.7);

# First Warmup set #
echo "<li>Do 8 reps with " . $FirstWarmupSet . " kgs, then take 1 minute rest.</li>";
echo "<br>";

# Second Warmup set #
echo "<li>Do 5 reps with " . $SecondWarmupSet . " kgs, then take 1 minute rest.</li>";
echo "<br>";
// etc etc...
```

I'd like the different variables values from PHP to be shown in my "#output" div when the user click on the submit button.

I've tried a lot of different things (AJAX without jQuery, AJAX with jQuery), but didn't manage to get what I want.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I'm sure my PHP script is working, since I used it without AJAX without any problem.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me on that.

Comment: I think you should go with jQuery. It's a simple calculation and no need to involve ajax, It can be done using jQuery without refreshing page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the easiest way to make an AJAX request for you is probably to try jQuery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Add jQuery on your HTML page -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Add some custom JavaScript file -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="warmupForm" class="form">
            <label for="userWorkLoad">Work load (in kgs)</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="userWorkLoad" id="userWorkLoad">
            <button id="btn" type="submit">Calculate</button>
        </form> 

        <div id="output">This is where I want the result to be shown with AJAX</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `script.js` content:

```js
$(function() {
    // Process a button click
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get input field
        var userWorkLoadInput = $("#userWorkLoad");

        // Build some request parameters
        var params = {
            userWorkLoad: userWorkLoadInput.val()
        };

        // Let's name your PHP script file as "server.php"
        // And send POST request with those parameters
        $.post("server.php", params, function(response) {
            // Response text we're going to put into the `output`
            $("#output").html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I'm now going to inspect each line of code and make sure I fully understand what's going on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using Jquery instead of using Ajax (using PHP you should add method="POST" to the form).
Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#send").click(function(){
// your calculates
$("#output").html(...);
});
});

...

<button type="submit" id="send">Calculate</button>
```